# Why doesn't a href link work while an onClick link does?

Tags: javascript, image, slider, href

In my jquery slider here, I am trying to wrap the images in  tags with href links. They are unresponsive. However, onclick="javascript:self.location.href='http://hodaradesign.com/'; return false;"  works fine. Why is that?

#### Doesn't work:

```
<a href="hodaradesign.com"><img id="book2" class="book" src="book2.png" /></a>
```

#### Works:

```
<img id="book3" class="book" src="book3.png" onclick="javascript:self.location.href='http://hodaradesign.com/'; return false;" />
```

#### Live demo:

http://www.freewaycreative.com/jsfun/fiddle.html

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your slider doesn't know or care about the `<a...>` element, it's only looking at elements with the class set to `book`!

Try this:

```
<a class="book" href="http://hodaradesign.com">
  <img id="book2" src="book2.png" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

well this looks somewhat like spaghetti code.

you dont need the `javascript:` handler in an onclick event as its already a javascript event. furthermore the `return false` in the onclick event will prevent the link from beeing followed if javascript is enabled and executed correctly.

something like this or some other listener is probably your problem.

Comment: That one works, though. this: <a href="..."><img src=""></a> doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you specified the href attribute on the `<img>` tag instead of the `<a>` tag.

it should be:

```
<a href="http://hodaradesign.com"><img id="book2" class="book" src="book2.png" /></a>
```

if you return false in a onlckick event handler, the event es bing prevented from being executed. in this case opening the link.

Comment: Did you see my source code? I put the href in the a tag around the image. it doesnt work. you know why?

Comment: try removing all javascript from your document.